# None value in python dictionary

Tags: python, if-statement, dictionary, nonetype

Is it possible to check none value in dict

```
dict = {'a':'None','b':'12345','c':'None'}
```

My code

```
for k,v in d.items():
  if d[k] != None:
    print "good"
  else:
    print "Bad
```

Prints three good after executing above code snippet.

```
good
good
good
```

Required:If value is None than not printing good for dict key a and c.

Answer (score 37):

Your none values are actually strings in your dictionary.

You can check for 'None'
or use actual python [None](http://docs.python.org/library/constants.html#None) value.

```
d = {'a':None,'b':'12345','c':None}

for k,v in d.items(): 
  if d[k] is None:
    print "good" 
  else: 
    print "Bad"
```

prints "good" 2 times

Or if you Have to use your current dictionary just change your check to look for `'None'`

additionally dict is a python built in type so it is a good idea not to name variables `dict`

Comment: Small nitpick, for the singleton ``None``, the best way to check is ``x is None`` or ``x is not None``.

Answer (score 10):

Define your dictionary with

```
d = {'a': None}
```

rather than

```
d = {'a': 'None'}
```

In the latter case, `'None'` is just a string, not Python's `None` type. Also, test for `None` with the identity operator `is`:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
    if value is None:
        print "None found!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using "if value is None" you can simply use

```
d = {'a':None, 'b':'12345', 'c':None, 'd':'None'}

for k, v in d.items():
    if v: 
        print("good")
    else: 
        print("bad")
```

"if v" will be True if there is any kind of value except None. Hence you don't have to explicitly use None keyword in if condition (if v is None).

```
Result:
bad
good
bad
good
```

In last case the value for key 'd' is 'None' - as a string not python value None

Comment: `if v` will test the truthiness of v.  if v is False, '', {}, etc, `if v` will return false. The OP is seeking a test for None.

Answer (score 1):

```
def none_in_dict(d):
    for _, value in d.items():
        if value is None:
            return True
    return False
```

And the use is:

```
if none_in_dict(my_dict):
    logger.error(my_err_msg)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the code output "good" for non None values and output "bad" for None values as in the example code of the o.p?

Comment: Sure :-) but the idea here is to have a generic function, so simply modify the use to the need: if not none_in_dict(my_dict): etc...