# If Dict value is null

Tags: python, dictionary

```
In [54]: User
Out[54]: {0: {'uid': ' rpatil\n'}, 1: {}}

In [55]: User[0]
Out[55]: {'uid': ' rpatil\n'}

In [56]: User[1]
Out[56]: {}

In [57]: if User[1] == '':
   ....:     print 'Null'
   ....:

In [58]:
```

So how to check Value is Null in multi dict

I've Tried Following Links but not work
[None value in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553938/none-value-in-python-dictionary)

Comment: What if `User[1]` is `0`. Do you want to check for just empty dict?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Empty dictionaries are falsey. Just use `if not dic`.

```
>>> testDict = {}
>>> if not testDict:
        print "Empty"


Empty
```

So, in your code.

```
>>> User = {0: {'uid': ' rpatil\n'}, 1: {}}
>>> if not User[1]:
        print "NULL"


NULL
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this since there are so many other things that are falsey.

Comment: @Surkit Kalra - Your way I think is more Pythonic, but I feel that my way is clearer... thoughts?

Comment: @kindall : Yeah, well, that kinda depends on what the OP wants. If he clears that up, I can maybe post something else.

Comment: @RyPeck: Yes, but as kindall points out, other things may be falsey too, so, if the OP specifically wants to test for an empty dictionary, then he'd have to go with your answer. :)

Comment: "Pythonic" isn't always what we should strive for. :) Nevertheless +1 to both your answers since I like them.

Comment: @kindall - Do you have a recommendation for this scenario?

Answer (score 5):

Empty dictionaries `== {}`. You could also test if it is an empty dictionary.

```
>>> t = {}
>>> t == None
False
>>> t == {}
True
```

With your code.

```
>>> User = {0: {'uid': ' rpatil\n'}, 1: {}}
>>> if User[1] == {}:
        print "NULL"

NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

`User[1]` isn't `None` - its value is the empty dict:

```
>>> User[1] == {}
True
```

You'd need to have:

```
>>> User = {0: {'uid': ' rpatil\n'}, 1: None}
```